# Recommended table name for many-to-many relationship Yii framework

Tags: php, yii2

What is recommended table name for many-to-many relationship in Yii framework. I dint find anything on it on `Yii Framework` application guide.

for example: `Package` and `Test` are related table then do i use

```
1. Package_Test
2. PackageTest
3. etc..
```

Comment: There is no recommended table name, why would you like this ?

Comment: I like to do `entity1_entity2`... but plural formats to represent the One or Many. Such as `package_tests` for One-to-Many, and `packages_tests` for Many-to-Many.

Answer (score 0):

There is no recommended way to name tables and columns in the database from Yii perspective. In this regards Yii is not particularly prescriptive.

I would suggest that your best choice is to use whatever naming you feel can be easily recognisable for a relationship table (as @Justinas suggested `package_to_test` might be a good solution, but `Package_Test could work as well).

The important part of naming is the ability to keep it consistent throughout the whole life of the project and be simple enough for anyone to pick it up, e.g. `$table1_to_$table2` can be an easy way to abstract the concept.

Hope this can help you.